# how to know if an asynchronous RPC is completed?

Tags: distributed-computing, rpc

Suppose I have an RPC call that takes the other process a very long time to complete, in this case, I'd better use an asynchronous RPC call to let the local process proceed to do some other work. How can the local process get notified when that RPC call is completed and returned?

What are the mechanisms that enable this kind of notification/communication?

Answer (score 0):

> How can the local process get notified when that RPC call is completed and returned?

It is dependent from API which you have to use. If you mean your own api which you are developing right now, then you need to choose method depend from your task and communication abilities.

> What are the mechanisms that enable this kind of notification/communication?

- immidiately reply - for quick task only, if task take too long time then return reply that task is too long and need to use polling or notification,
- polling (http) - simultaneously poll task done status,
- long polling (http) - same but reply little delayed to be more real time in the opposite direction but makes it impossible to realtime in the forward direction,
- fullduplex bidirectional protocol - tcp/udp/websocket/etc - using notification message to notify about task state is done.

Comment: pooling => polling

Answer (score 0):

Some flavors of RPC can call you back at a method of your choosing when the remote operation is complete.